kartoza/mapproxy performance issues
So I've been looking into containerization of a deployed normal MapProxy. Where I decided to use kartoza/mapproxy instead of the official docker image. However it seems like I am not getting anywhere close to the same performance with this version.
It is configured to use 2 cpus and 4 threads, the same as the old mapproxy but it takes about 5 times as long to fetch a map. It is configured in multi_mapproxy mode and running version 3.1.2.
It also seem like the cpu usage never goes up to 100%, it stays around 40% max and looking at the network logs it seems to get stuck fetching parts of the maps for a long time.
